# Writing a loop to create multiple dataframes by subsetting data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I'm having trouble with the following: If I wanted to go through my dataframe and save "survival" at each "dose" at a specified time (let's say time =11) for each line and sex combination, into separate dataframes and then save each of those dataframes, how could I do that in R?

| Time | Survival | Line | Sex | Dose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 0.95 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 30 | 0.85 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 32 | 0.75 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 11 | 0.45 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 15 | 0.15 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 16 | 0.25 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 18 | 0.15 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 40 | 0.25 | 138 | F | 1 |
| 28 | 0.95 | 138 | F | 10 |
| 30 | 0.85 | 138 | F | 10 |
| 32 | 0.75 | 138 | F | 10 |
| 11 | 0.65 | 138 | F | 10 |
| 15 | 0.15 | 138 | F | 10 |
| 16 | 0.25 | 138 | F | 10 |
| 18 | 0.15 | 138 | F | 10 |
| 40 | 0.25 | 138 | F | 10 |
| 28 | 0.95 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 30 | 0.85 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 32 | 0.75 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 11 | 0.45 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 15 | 0.15 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 16 | 0.25 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 18 | 0.15 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 40 | 0.25 | 138 | M | 1 |
| 28 | 0.95 | 138 | M | 10 |
| 30 | 0.85 | 138 | M | 10 |
| 32 | 0.75 | 138 | M | 10 |
| 11 | 0.35 | 138 | M | 10 |
| 15 | 0.15 | 138 | M | 10 |
| 16 | 0.25 | 138 | M | 10 |
| 18 | 0.15 | 138 | M | 10 |
| 40 | 0.25 | 138 | M | 10 |
| 28 | 0.95 | 140 | F | 10 |
| 30 | 0.85 | 140 | F | 10 |
| 32 | 0.75 | 140 | F | 10 |
| 11 | 0.45 | 140 | F | 10 |
| 15 | 0.15 | 140 | F | 10 |
| 16 | 0.25 | 140 | F | 10 |
| 18 | 0.15 | 140 | F | 10 |
| 40 | 0.25 | 140 | F | 10 |
| 28 | 0.95 | 140 | M | 10 |
| 30 | 0.85 | 140 | M | 10 |
| 32 | 0.75 | 140 | M | 10 |
| 11 | 0.45 | 140 | M | 10 |
| 15 | 0.15 | 140 | M | 10 |
| 16 | 0.25 | 140 | M | 10 |
| 18 | 0.15 | 140 | M | 10 |
| 40 | 0.25 | 140 | M | 10 |

I would like the resulting dataframe to look like this: Let's say for females of line 138 at time=11:

| Survival | Dose |
| --- | --- |
| 0.45 | 1 |
| 0.65 | 10 |

And I want to do that for each line and sex combination at time=11 in my dataframe, and make new dataframes for the survival and dose for each each line and sex combination and save those.

Comment: Are you ask to do it with a for-loop? Other approaches may be more R-like.

Comment: I'd like to use the easiest method possible. Maybe a for-loop is not the easiest?

Answer (score 2):

You can do `split()` like

```
ls_df <- split(data, list(data$Time, data$Line, data$Sex))
```

That is a list of data frames. The first looks like

```
> ls_df[[1L]]
   Time Survival Line Sex Dose
4    11     0.45  138 F      1
12   11     0.65  138 F     10
```

Please note that some data frames are empty because their factor combinations do not exist. How should we deal with these? I suggest to delete them:

```
ls_df <- ls_df[sapply(ls_df, \(x) dim(x)[1L]) > 0L]
```

If you really want to copy the remaining list entries to your current environment do

```
list2env(x = ls_df, envir = environment())
```

If you really want to write them to hard disk seperately, one option is

```
path <- getwd() # path to your current directory 
invisible(
  lapply(
    X = names(ls_df), 
    FUN = \(i) write.csv(x = ls_df[[i]], file = paste0(file.path(path, i), ".csv"))
  )
)
```

You need to set path in a previous step to a directory of your choice like `path <- getwd()`.

---

Data:

```
data <- structure(
  list(
    Time = c(
      "28",
      "30",
      "32",
      "11",
      "15",
      "16",
      "18",
      "40",
      "28",
      "30",
      "32",
      "11",
      "15",
      "16",
      "18",
      "40",
      "28",
      "30",
      "32",
      "11",
      "15",
      "16",
      "18",
      "40",
      "28",
      "30",
      "32",
      "11",
      "15",
      "16",
      "18",
      "40",
      "28",
      "30",
      "32",
      "11",
      "15",
      "16",
      "18",
      "40",
      "28",
      "30",
      "32",
      "11",
      "15",
      "16",
      "18",
      "40"
    ),
    Survival = c(
      "0.95",
      "0.85",
      "0.75",
      "0.45",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.95",
      "0.85",
      "0.75",
      "0.65",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.95",
      "0.85",
      "0.75",
      "0.45",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.95",
      "0.85",
      "0.75",
      "0.35",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.95",
      "0.85",
      "0.75",
      "0.45",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.95",
      "0.85",
      "0.75",
      "0.45",
      "0.15",
      "0.25",
      "0.15",
      "0.25"
    ),
    Line = c(
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "138",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140",
      "140"
    ),
    Sex = c(
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "F",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M",
      "M"
    ),
    Dose = c(
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10",
      "10"
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,
                -48L)
```